# How can i open and write in cron file task using symfony2

Tags: symfony, console, cron, command, cron-task

I'm creating an application in Symfony2.4. I also have the command, I want to add the command  in cron a task using symfony2, not manually namely, the via symfony2, open and write. Any suggestions to get this done.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

faost thanks. but I know how to add in cron manually via the console, I was interested how it do  through the controller. In short, I found the solution :)

---

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * command'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
echo exec('crontab /crontab.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a console command ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html))
2. Add to cron execution of your command. For example, run a command at 2 a. m. every day:

   $ crontab -e

   0 2 * * * php /var/www/example.com/app/console mybundle:mycommand

Comment: Thank you. and how to add the command in cron directly from the controller?

Comment: You can do it in terminal by command "crontab -e". See more (for ubuntu): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto